# Evaluating static constructors of modules with reflection

Tags: f#, system.reflection, static-constructor

I have a lot of modules that upon starting the program are supposed to add certain things to a single Dictionary found in a higher level module. However, it appears that expressions and constants within a module are packed into static constructors when compiling to a Console App, so these aren't evaluated unless explicitly referenced/when the program thinks they are needed.

There have been a few questions on here regarding initializing modules, and the consensus has been that it is not possible to force. However, I have not seen any of them explore reflection in this regard. In C# I know you are able to invoke the static constructor of a type, so I have attempted the same with F# modules.

My attempts have involved adding a custom attribute (MessageHandlerAttribute) to each module containing such an expression that I want evaluated upon starting the program, and then running this:

```
let initAllMessageHandlerModules =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() 
    |> Array.choose (fun typ -> 
        typ.CustomAttributes 
        |> Seq.tryFind (fun attr -> attr.AttributeType = typeof<MessageHandlerAttribute>)
        |> Option.map (fun _ -> typ))
    |> Array.iter 
        (fun typ -> try typ.TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null) |> ignore with | ex -> printfn "%A" ex)
```

But this gives me the following error: 
**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I have also tried to swap the final lambda function with this:

```
(fun typ -> try System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typ.TypeHandle) |> ignore with | ex -> printfn "%A" ex)
```

But this appears to do nothing. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: As an aside - if you're already using reflection to invoke those, couldn't you put the initialization code in a normal static method instead? (That might be easier to invoke via reflection...)

Comment: Yes you're right, that's what I'm currently doing to make it work. The initialization code of these modules is just placed in functions (that I attach the custom attribute to instead of the module) that only take a unit-argument and are invoked through dynamic method invocation. The only issue I have with this is that it's going to fail in places I forget to add the ()-argument to make them functions as opposed to constants. I just hoped this type initializer approach would work, in the spirit of "if it compiles, it's probably correct".

Comment: You're using `Seq.tryFind`, and `Seq`s are lazily evaluated -- could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't think so; the module types are indeed successfully found by this pipeline. However, the final lambda function fails in initializing their static constructors (which I don't even know is necessarily possible).

Answer (score 0):

Use type.GetConstructor instead of type.TypeInitializer.

```
(fun typ -> try typ.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public, null, CallingConventions.Standard, Array.empty<Type>, Array.empty<ParameterModifier>).Invoke(null, null) |> ignore with | ex -> printfn "%A" ex)
```

[Here](http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-reflection-constructors) are some more examples